# adding dynamic number of days to a particular date in script

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a date for example: 20160808 which is stored in a variable $d_date.
I have another variable that contains the number of days I need to add to the d_date. Which is $days.
Lets say $days=378.
I want to add 378 days to $d_date in my script. But it seems to ignore the $days when I use the following command.

```
end=`date -d "$d_date +$days days" +%Y%m%d`
```

When I debug the script it shows the following (related to this command):

```
++ date -d '20160808 + days' +%Y%m%d
+ end=572160721
```

Comment: $days=378 or days=378 ?  It's looks like you either have a typo somewhere, or you're leaving out some other critical detail.

Comment: How did you initialize days? Do `echo $days` to see if $days is correctly initialized.

Comment: @Eric : I calulate both $d_date and $days in the script. To be clear
end=`date -d "$d_date +$days days" +%Y%m%d`
should translate to 
end=`date -d "20160808 +378 days" +%Y%m%d`

Comment: @PierreFrançois yes.. I calculate $days before this command and echo $days to see if it prints the desired number (i.e 378)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
d_date=20160808
days=378
end=`date -d "$d_date +$days days" +%Y%m%d`
echo $end
```

It gives next output:

> 20170821

Comment: yes I tried this in another script and it seem to work. Then only thing left is to check if there is any empty spaces or hidden stuff when I calculate $days.. which doesn't show when I echo $days.

Comment: @TejaswiN: To see hidden chars in `$days`, run `echo $days | od -bc`

Comment: It worked now.. Thaks! :)
There were some hidden characters somehow added during my the calculation.